# Why does my cron job spawn multiple processes?

Tags: cron

I'm fairly new at using cron jobs. I'm using Webmin to create the cron job as shown here [image]

The actual command I'm running is

ffmpeg -y -i rtsp://xxx:xxx@xxx.org:8127/live -vframes 1 /var/www/html/mac/garage/garage.jpg

Which basically grabs a frame form a rtsp stream and stores it in a folder every 5 minutes.

However after a while when I check the running processes (because I see my memory usage is being eaten up I seem multiple processes of the same command.

[image]

I do know sometimes the rtsp stream crashes. Does it spawn another process if the cron job command is not successful?

Thanks.

Comment: what happens if you run the command line in a terminal?

Comment: The contrast of you images is terrible I can not read them.

Comment: Rather than show the GUI that sets up cron, you could show the text version of the resultant crontab file: `crontab -l`.

Comment: I had a thread yesterday on Reddit about ffprobe (part of the ffmpeg package). It has about 150 options (very messy). You might see if adding the `-v error` option provides further information. Also, cron sends email to your Linux user mailbox unless you redirect absolutely everything: you might find something helpful in your mailbox. You might even manage this problem with a `timeout` command.